# How to show a message when app is launched

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to show a message or a xaml page when the application(for windows phone 7) is launched and that message should be shown only once(i.e, that message should not visible from the next time the application is launched? Can anybody help me with this. Thanks in advance for your hard work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this, http://www.jimmycollins.org/blog/?p=366

It allows you to check if first run before a page is displayed so you have the option to display a different page.  In your case you will display the same page but you could pass an indication to the main page or put similar first run logic in your main page.

If you add a version to settings you can check for first run after update as well.